# DSP32C doesn't have a timer but need a timer implementation

Tags: timer, signal-processing

I have this old DSP32C with me and wanted to implement a timer based control. Eventually when I started reading the datasheet, I found out that there is no timer register in the DSP32C.

Is there any possible way I could implement a function similar to timer.. say 'after 3seconds, do this...'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot solve this "internally", you'll need to find a suitable Real-Time Clock (RTC) component that can interface with the DSP32C. Which one and how to connect it is probably a question for the [Electrical Engineering StackExchange site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Depending on what you want to do, a [busy loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) might also be a solution: you simply loop a certain number of times. If you don't have precise timing information and can calculate the number of loops, you'll have to try out with a stop watch and tweak your loop(s) until it's taking long enough.

Comment: Thank you DarkDust. My program is supposed to execute without any delay loop in between. So I guess as you said, additional hardware chip is the only way to go.